# Mapping propertie for all entities using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, entity, fluent

I need to set a property "DynamicUpdate();" for all entities in my project, but I don't want to duplicate the code in every classmaps, how do it?

An example of my classmaps now:

```
   public CStatMessagesVOMap()
        {
            DynamicUpdate();
            Table("TBCSTATMESSAGES");
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Cstat).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Message).Length(500).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Allowed).Not.Nullable();
            References(x => x.DocumentKind).Column("DOCUMENTKIND").Cascade.None();
        }

 public DocumentKindVOMap()
        {
            DynamicUpdate();
            Table("TBDOCUMENTKIND");
            Id(x => x.DocumentKind).Column("DOCUMENTKIND");
            Map(x => x.Name).Length(20).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.DocumentKind).CustomType<short>().Not.Nullable();
            HasMany(x => x.Messages).KeyColumn("DOCUMENTKIND").Inverse().Cascade.All();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to inherit your classes from `AbstractMap<T>` and this `AbstractMap<T>` inherits from `ClassMap<T>`, so on the constructor you could call the `DynamicUpdate()`.

```
  public class AbstractMap<T> : ClassMap<T>
    {
        public AbstractMap()
        {
            DynamicUpdate();
        }
    }

 public class CStatMessagesVOMap : AbstractMap<CstatMessagesVO>
    {
        public CStatMessagesVOMap()
        {
            Table("TBCSTATMESSAGES");
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Cstat).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Message).Length(500).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Allowed).Not.Nullable();
            References(x => x.DocumentKind).Column("DOCUMENTKIND").Cascade.None();
        }
```

In this case, all classes inherited from `AbstractMap<T>` would call the method you want.